# Find closest value in a list in C# with linq?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, indexing

I've a list like this:

```
public List<Dictionary<int, int>> blanks { get; set; }
```

This keep some index values:

[image]

In addition I have also a variable named X. X can take any value. I want to find closest 'Key' value to X. For example:

If X is 1300, I want to take blanks index: 2 and Key: 1200. 
How can I do this via linq? Or, is there any other solution?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: What if it is not a Dictionary. What if it is a List like this:

`List<List<int[]>> lastList = new List<List<int[]>>();`

[image]

This time, I want to take first List's indexes and second List's index. For example, if X is 800, I want to take 0 and 0 (for index 0) and also take 1 and 1 (for index 1) How can I do this time?

Comment: If each dictionary has count 1, why not use a List of keyvaluepairs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var diffs = blanks.SelectMany((item, index) => item.Select(entry => new
            { 
              ListIndex = index, // Index of the parent dictionary in the list 
              Key = entry.Key, // Key
              Diff = Math.Abs(entry.Key - X) // Diff between key and X
            }));

var closestDiff = diffs.Aggregate((agg, item) => (item.Diff < agg.Diff) ? item : agg);

Dictionary<int, int> closestKeyDict = blanks[closestKey.ListIndex];
int closestKey = closestDiff.Key;
int closestKeyValue = closestKeyDict[closestKey];
```

The [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).ASPx) clause flattens all the dictionaries entries into a collection of { ListIndex, DictionaryKey, Difference } instances.

This flattened collection is then aggregated to retrieve the item with the minimum difference.

To answer your second questsion:

```
var diffs = blanks.SelectMany((list, listIndex) => list.
                   SelectMany((array, arrayIndex) => array.
                   Select((item, itemIndex) => new
                   { 
                     ListIndex = listIndex,
                     ArrayIndex = arrayIndex,
                     ItemIndex = itemIndex,
                     Diff = Math.Abs(item - X) 
                   })));

var closestDiff = diffs.Aggregate((agg, item) => (item.Diff < agg.Diff) ? item : agg);
```

Now in `closestDiff` you'll find the indices of the closes item (List index, array index and array item index)

Comment: What is everyone's obsession with doing a whole O(n^2) `OrderBy` just to get a single maximum or minimum value?

Comment: @Rawling The sorted items do not contain only the difference but also the list index + the dictionary key

Comment: You still don't need to order the whole list just to find which is the minimum.

Comment: @Rawling, I've replaced it with an Aggregate call

Comment: @vc74 Your solution in below is working fine :

var diffs = kaynaklarArray[l].blanks.SelectMany((item, index) => item.Select(entry => new { Index = index, Key = entry.Key, Diff = Math.Abs(entry.Key - X) })).OrderBy(item => item.Diff);

var closestDiff = diffs.First();

var key = closestDiff.Key;

var value = (kaynaklarArray[l].blanks[closestDiff.Index])[closestDiff.Key];

Comment: What if it is not a Dictionary. What if it is a List like this:         List<List<int[]>> blanks = new List<List<int[]>>();

What is the solution for this?

Comment: @team16sah A list with the dictionary keys? what about the dictionary values?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. But I take an error like this:                 


The type or namespace name 'Select' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61556/discussion-between-vc-74-and-team16sah).

Comment: @vc-74 if the blanks has more than 1 item (blanks.Count>1), the solution doesn't work. I want to use this for each list items. Is there possible?

Comment: @team16sah Did you get an error message? This should work regardless of the number of items in blanks

Comment: On my current sample, even though blanks has 2 items, closestDiff's  LıstIndex notever be 2.

Comment: List indexes are 0 based so it will be either 0 or 1

Comment: So, what can I do? Could you please send a sample?

Comment: @team16sah I don't understand your question. List indexes are 0 based, if ListIndex is 1 it means it's the second item.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I wrote wrong expression. LıstIndex is never be 1, although blanks has 2 items.

Comment: var diff = lastList.SelectMany((listS, listIndex) => listS.SelectMany((array, arrayIndex) => array.Select((item, itemIndex) => new
{   ListIndex = listIndex,
    ArrayIndex = arrayIndex,
    ItemIndex = itemIndex,
    Diff = Math.Abs(item - X)
})));

var closest = diff.Aggregate((agg, item) => (item.Diff < agg.Diff) ? item : agg);

for (int x = closest.ListIndex; x < lastList.Count; x++)
{
    .
    .
    for (int y = closest.ArrayIndex; y < lastList[x].Count; y++)
    {
        .
        .
    }
}
In this section, lastList has 2 items (0 and 1). However LıstIndex never has 1 index.

Comment: I meant, please update your original question or create a new one

Comment: lastList[closestDiff.ListIndex][closestDiff.ArrayIndex][closestDiff.ItemIndex]

Comment: Dear @vc-74, thanks for your patiently support. I use your first answer for my first question. I need one more help. I want to closest AND SMALLER key and index. So, if X is 1300 and the values are 1200 and 1350, I need 1200, because it is SMALLER than X. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @team16sah Please create a new question, this space is getting messy

Comment: I created a new question for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037534/find-closest-and-smaller-value-in-a-list-in-c-sharp-with-linq

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most optimized way but it should just work,

```
List<Dictionary<int, int>> blanks = new List<Dictionary<int, int>>
{
    new Dictionary<int, int>{{100,200}},
    new Dictionary<int, int>{{500,200}},
    new Dictionary<int, int>{{700,200}},
    new Dictionary<int, int>{{1200,200}},
    new Dictionary<int, int>{{300,200}},
    new Dictionary<int, int>{{200,200}},
    new Dictionary<int, int>{{800,200}},
};

int x = 1300;

IEnumerable<int> keys = blanks.SelectMany(ints => ints.Keys);
var diff = keys.Select(i => Math.Abs(i - x)).ToList();
var index = diff.IndexOf(diff.Min());
var value = blanks[index].Keys.First();
```

Comment: This solution also working fine and fast. So, What if it is not a Dictionary. What if it is a List like this: List<List<int[]>> blanks = new List<List<int[]>>(); What is the solution for this?