# Find closest and smaller value in a list in C# with linq?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, indexing

I've a list like this:

```
public List<Dictionary<int, int>> blanks { get; set; }
```

This keep some index values:

[image]

In addition I have also a variable named X. X can take any value. I want to find closest and smaller 'Key' value to X. I can take only closest value via this code block. But, it can't take smaller one.

```
var diffs = kaynaklarArray[l].blanks.SelectMany((item, index) => item.Select(entry => new { Index = index, Key = entry.Key, Diff = Math.Abs(entry.Key - X) })).OrderBy(item => item.Diff);
var closestDiff = diffs.First();
var key = closestDiff.Key;
var value = (kaynaklarArray[l].blanks[closestDiff.Index])[closestDiff.Key];
```

if X is 1000, I want to take blanks index: 1 and Key: 750, because it is SMALLER than X. However this code block takes index:2 and Key: 1200. I don't want it.

How can I do this?

In addition I've also a List like this:

```
List<List<int[]>> lastList = new List<List<int[]>>();
```

[image]

This time, I want to take first List's indexes and second List's index. For example, if X is 800, I want to take 0 and 0 (for index 0) and also take 1 and 1 (for index 1).

Again, I have code block for this. But it can't take smaller one. It takes closest one.

```
var diffSecond = lastList.SelectMany((listS, listIndex) => listS.
SelectMany((array, arrayIndex) => array.Select((item, itemIndex) => new
{
    ListIndex = listIndex,
    ArrayIndex = arrayIndex,
    ItemIndex = itemIndex,
    Diff = Math.Abs(item - X)
})));

var closestDiffS = diffSecond.Aggregate((agg, item) => (item.Diff < agg.Diff) ? item : agg);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find closest value in a list in C# with linq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910324/find-closest-value-in-a-list-in-c-sharp-with-linq)

Comment: Add a Where(item < X) somewhere

Comment: @Xaruth Because that question's comments have too flood, I created a new question.

Comment: @Dennis_E is right. Your code is doing exactly what you want. You need to limit it with a where of some sort. Either before the select or after.... but DEFINITELY before the First()

Comment: Where should I place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Diff = Math.Abs(item - X)
```

to

```
Diff = X - item
```

and then

```
var closestDiffS = diffSecond.Aggregate((agg, item) => (item.Diff > 0 && item.Diff < agg.Diff) ? item : agg);
```

Or, you need a Where. I think it's supposed to go here:

```
var diffSecond = lastList.SelectMany((listS, listIndex) => listS.
SelectMany((array, arrayIndex) => array //Not here, 'cause you need the index
.Select((item, itemIndex) => new
{
    ListIndex = listIndex,
    ArrayIndex = arrayIndex,
    ItemIndex = itemIndex,
    Diff = X - item
}).Where(item => item.Diff > 0)
));
```

To get all the lists with the smallest Diff:

```
var closestDiffS = diffSecond.GroupBy(item => item.Diff).OrderBy(group => group.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks. What can be the solution for my first question that has Dictionary?

Comment: Same thing, basically. `var diffs = kaynaklarArray[l].blanks.SelectMany((item, index) => item.Select(entry => new { Index = index, Key = entry.Key, Diff = X - entry.Key }).Where(item => item.Diff > 0)).OrderBy(item => item.Diff);`

Comment: Your answer's second solution and above sample code give an error for 'item': http://i.imgur.com/k2lTTMd.png

Comment: I think you're missing a parentheses (after the Where?)

Comment: No. I copied and pasted your code block and I take same error. There must be another problem.

Comment: I think I used a name that was already in scope. Try changing 'item' (inside the Where) to something else.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is not that. I take this error this time : An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll
Additional information:Sequence contains no elements

Comment: If all keys are greater than X, diffs will be empty and `diffs.First();` will give you that error. Debug your program. I don't have enough information.

Comment: You are right, thanks. In addition, if lastList has more than 1 lists, the diffSecond isn't working exact. It everytime returns 1 item. So, if lastList has 3 items, diffSecond must return 3 items. Am I right? What can I do for straight data?

Comment: is there an answer for my above question?

Comment: This time, I can't access closestDiffs.ListIndex etc. So, it is not useful for me.

Comment: diffSecond does not return just 1 item. It returns ALL items where Diff > 0. The edited closestDiff returns a group containing all items that have Diff equal to the smallest Diff. The closestDiff I wrote before only returns the first one.